# How do I show that LibraryMember can borrow 6 copies while staff can borrow 12?

Tags: uml

I am trying to show that LibraryMember can borrow up to 6 copies, and staff can borrow up to 12, while also showing inheritance. How can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If instances of `LibraryMember` are constrained to have at most 6 links to instances of `Copy` and `MemberOfStaff` is a subclass of `LibraryMember`, then it inherits this constraint and, consequently, instances of `MemberOfStaff` also must not have more than 6 links to instances of `Copy`.

Therefore, if you don't want to inherit this constraint, you cannot make `MemberOfStaff` a subclass of `LibraryMember`.